# Error in json post request for mailchimp api

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mailchimp

I am trying to create a wrapper for: 
[this mailchimp method](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/interest-grouping-add.php.) using C#.Net

I understand that there are already .Net wrappers available. I am using [Mailchimp.Net](https://github.com/danesparza/MailChimp.NET)  by Dan Esparza. Method in the wrapper class is giving exception for  the api method mentioned above.It is throwing internal server exception (500) which I am not sure why, so I decided to create my own wrapper for the particular method. I have following code:

```
private void CreateGrouping(string apiKey, string listId,string groupName,string groupValue)
        {
            string url = "https://us9.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/lists/interest-grouping-add";

            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);



            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            List<string> values = new List<string>();
            values.Add(groupValue);

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
                {
                    apiKey = apiKey,
                    id  = listId,
                    name = groupName,
                    type="radio",
                    groups = values

                });
                streamWriter.Write(json);
            }


            var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```

But on execution of `var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();` is throwing same exception  - internal server error (500).
It might be that I am passing data in wrong way ? Can someone please help me in finding out what am I missing here ?

Comment: Internal server error (500) at least for web applications means it has been stopped and is not currently working.

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected I was passing the data in wrong way: apiKey has to be apikey (k was in caps)

```
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
                {
                    apikey = apiKey,
                    id  = listId,
                    name = groupName,
                    type="radio",
                    groups = values

                });
```

Other than this, I added:

```
streamWriter.Flush();
streamWriter.Close();
```

It might help someone save sometime.